# How to convert object values in 2-depth to typescript union without using `String` indexing?

Tags: typescript, object, union

```
// from
const obj = {
  a: {
    aa: 'A',
    cc: 'C',
  },
  b: {
    bb: 'B',
    cc: 'C',
  }
} as const;

// to
type ObjValue = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
```

Hi, I want to get union type from object.

So I tried with `typeof obj[keyof typeof obj]` pattern, but it just returns this.

```
type ObjValue = 'C'
```

How do I get the union type composed only string values of object without `String` indexing?

Comment: Do you need this to work for arbitrarily nested depths? If so, [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ8LVW) might work for you.  If you only care about depth 2 then a hardcoded approach like the existing answer should suffice.  Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the `typeof obj[keyof typeof obj]` pattern does not really work with unions. Using mapped types solves the problem though.

```
type ObjValue = {
  [K in keyof typeof obj]: typeof obj[K][keyof (typeof obj[K])]  
}[keyof typeof obj]

// type ObjValue = "A" | "C" | "B"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=20&pln=13&pc=1#code/PTAEDMCcHsFsCgDG0B2BnALqaAjAVqALygDe8ooAhgFynkVU2gDkAgswDT0WKK3MBhTvQC+XCjlpkGoHJJYAhYTN78h40CPgiqaUMnQYA3PHgYAngAcApqADy+AGqUANgFdbxaaADaAaVAASxRQAGtrc2hwUAsbKOx8AF1aWOt43Dx-RJ9wyOiAClT0-CyASkSKbRyI+KLojMTTEBirWwc8Z3dPUAAiVh7QAB9egQHhnoUeoA)

Comment: it doesn't work with unions because types are contravariant in their keys, so `keyof (A | B)` is equivalent to `(keyof A) & (keyof B)`.  For example, a value of type `{a: string, b: number} | {b: string, c: number}` is only known to have a `b` key; it cannot be safely indexed with `a` or `c`.  In general,`(A | B)[keyof (A | B)]` is not equivalent to `A[keyof A] | B[keyof B]`.  If you want the latter, you need to distribute the `T[keyof T]` operation over unions in `T`, which can be done in a number of ways including the mapped type technique you're doing here

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! It works as intended. I try to learn about typescript more and more..